# Add and Remove views from Toolbar depending on Fragment Displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have an application, that at the moment only has 2 fragments.  Fragment 1, this has the nav drawer and the title.

Fragment 2 requires a custom view as adding menu items won't work as I need alignment.  So I add the view as follows:

```
 ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.LEFT);

    //Remove nav drawer "hamburger"
    mMainActivity.mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

    //Remove title from Toolbar
    bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
       View postToolBar = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_content_toolbar, null);

    mMainActivity.mToolBar.addView(postToolBar, params);
```

That is fine and it displays correctly.  However, when I want to return to the previous fragment Fragment 1, I then call `mMainActivity.mToolBar.removeView(postToolBar);`  I call this on return to Fragment 1 as the user can navigate either by the back button or by button in the postToolBar.  However, the view is still in place.  I can't get rid of it.  I have now tried setting the visibility to GONE but that won't work either.

This was pretty simple with the Action Bar, however things seem to have gotten a bit complicated with the Tool bar.

I must add that in each of my two fragments I extend a BaseFragment in which I declare the toolbar view.

Can any one help or send me in the direction of a tutorial?

Comment: @Lazai can you remove views from the toolbar in that method?

Comment: if you had put your button as an item, you can.

Comment: @Lazai As stated in my question I have a custom view, I don't have menu items as I require custom alignment, that was all in the question

Answer (score 0):

This is how i achieved it at this time:

in activity onCreateView();

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // enable overriding the default toolbar_home layout
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // disable the default title element here (for centered title)
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            cutomToolbarView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_toolbar_home, null);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(cutomToolbarView);

    }
```

and here is two simple method to do the magic

```
public void setToolbarTitleEnabled(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}

public void setCustomToolbarEnabled() {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}
```

then simply when you can change actionbar like these:

when to select HomeFragment.java or whatever in your case

```
setToolbarTitleEnabled(CURRENT_TAG);
```

and when to select other fragment:

```
setCustomToolbarEnabled();
```